# @ReleaseStrategy - Spring Integration - Custom implementation

Tags: java, spring-integration

Please let me know if there is way to define @ReleaseStrategy with MessageGroup and associate it with @Aggregator.

I have POJO defined as below but not sure how would I associate a @Aggregator to it

```java
public class FooReleaseStrategy {

      @ReleaseStrategy
      public boolean canRelease(MessageGroup group) {
         return group.isComplete();
      }

}
```

I have @Aggregator and @CorrelationStratgy defined part of configuration.

```java
      @Aggregator(inputChannel="sftpChannel" outputChannel="aggregateChannel")
         public List<Message<?>> aggregateFiles(List<Message<?>> messages) {
         return messages;
      }
```

@CorrelationStrategy based on filename.

Would be very helpful if someone can shed some light on @ReleaseStrategy association with example if possible.

Based on the comments, I am planning on the create a aggregator factory bean to see if works for my use-case

```java
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public FactoryBean<MessageHandler> aggregatorFactoryBean( ) {
        AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
        aggregatorBean.setProcessorBean(new CustomAggregator());
        aggregatorBean.setMethodName("aggregate");
        aggregatorBean.setMessageStore(new SimpleMessageStore());
        aggregatorBean.setReleaseStrategy(messageGroup -> {
            return messageGroup.isComplete();
        });
        aggregatorBean.setOutputChannel(aggregatorFileChannel());
        aggregatorBean.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
        aggregatorBean.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(1000L));
        aggregatorBean.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(false);
        aggregatorBean.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
        return aggregatorBean;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an `@Aggregator`, `@ReleaseStrategy` and `@CorrelationStrategy`, consider to configure an `AggregatorFactoryBean` as a `@Bean` and apply a `@SerivceActivator` annotation on it for those `inputChannel` and `outputChannel`.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.4.0-M2/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator-annotations

Answer (score 0):

When using that style of configuration, `@Aggregator`, `@CorrelationStrategy` and `@ReleasStrategy` are usually in the same bean.

You can, however, define a `ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean` bean that will provide an implementation of `ReleaseStrategy` based on your POJO method.

```
setTarget(myRSBean);
```

It will find the annotation.